# I need a data structure just like stack but with Random Access but, what should I implement?

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, stl, stack

I am trying to implement Tarjan's Strongly Connected Component's Algorithm but however I am having difficulty because the [psuedo-code](http://fmt.cs.utwente.nl/files/sprojects/252.pdf) (Page 17) demands me to search through the stack but I know stack does not provide Random Access facility. I personally think this is not an appropriate pseudo-code because they are using the wrong data structure. Can you either suggest me an alternate pseudocode or an alternate data structure?

Comment: `vector` even has `push_back()` and `pop_back()` which are stack operations. It's almost as if it was designed to be stack when you need it to be one :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Stack is a container adaptor and under the hub (by default) it uses `vector`. It can also use `deque` or `list` if one likes.

This means that `vector` provides all the functions necessary to carry out stack operations. `vector` uses `RandomAccessIterator`.
The same applies to `deque`.

`list` uses a `BidirectionalIterator` and would not suite your needs.

My suggestion is to use `vector` for your task.